# Some notation in local field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, local-field

If K is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let W = K($\sqrt[p^n]{b}$), where b $\in$ K$^{\times}$. How can I understand W? And what does K$^{\times p}$ mean?

Comment: $(K^\times)^p=\{a^p,a\in K^\times\}$. Assume $\zeta_p\in K$. If $b\not\in (K^\times)^p$ then $b^{1/p}$ minimal polynomial is $f(x)=\prod_{j=1}^l (x-\zeta_p^{e_j} b^{1/p})$ and $f(0)\in K$ implies $l=p=[K(b^{1/p}):K]$. If $c \in b^m(K^\times)^p$ then $K(c^{1/p})\subset K(b^{1/p})$. For the converse, if $c^{1/p}\in K(b^{1/p}), c^{1/p} \not \in K$ with $\sigma(b^{1/p}) = \zeta_p b^{1/p}\in Gal(K(b^{1/p})/K)$ then $c^{1/p}=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1} b^{n/p} u_n,u_n \in K$ and 
$\sigma(c^{1/p}) = \zeta_p^m c^{1/p}$ implies $c^{1/p} = u_m b^{m/p}, c\in b^m (K^\times)^p$. The case $\zeta_p \not\in K$ follows.

Comment: Next the group $K^\times/(K^\times)^p = (\pi_K^{\Bbb{Z}} O_K^\times)/((\pi_K^p)^{\Bbb{Z}} (O_K^\times)^p) \cong \pi_K^{\Bbb{Z/pZ}} \times O_K^\times/(O_K^\times)^p$ which is a finite group because the binomial series for $(1+x)^{1/p}$ converges for $|x|_p < ..$